# State not updated correctly between custom Context provider and top level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I followed the recipe from this video and it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LrDIWkK_Bc&t=182s

My use case is the following. I have application state including: user details and whether the backend including database is live or not as part of my custom application context so I can propagate that data downstream to all components without having to pass it explicitly - reminds me a bit of Scala's implicits btw but let's not digress.

I define my custom Application context like this:

```
export const AppDataContext = React.createContext({
    appData: {user: undefined, checkLive: true},
    setAppData: () => {} // TBD later 
});

export default const AppDataContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [appData, setAppData] = useState({user: undefined, checkLive: true});

    // initialize the data 
    useEffect() => {
        // ... compute the data by calling remote endpoint APIs
        // populate the data state for this context and any interested data receiver
        setAppData(data);
        props.setAppData && props.setAppData(data); 
    }, []);

    return (
        <AppDataContext.Provider value={{ appData, setAppData }}>
            {props.children}
        </AppDataContext.Provider> 
    );
};
```

I can now access that data from any child component like so:

```
const {appData, setAppData} = useContext(AppDataContext);
```

However it doesn't work like that on the top level where I also need it:

```
export default const App = () => {
    // I can't do this, because it is outside the scope of AppDataContextProvider
    const {appData, setAppData} = useContext(AppDataContext);    

    return (
        <Router>
            <AppDataContextProvider> 
            </AppDataContextProvider> 
        </Router>
    );
};
```

therefore I change my App.jsx to instead do:

```
export default const App = () => {
    const [appData, setAppData] = useState(null);

    return (
        <Router>
            <AppDataContextProvider setAppData={setAppData}> 
                 // now use it like
                 {appData && appData.user && (
                     // some content
                 )}
            </AppDataContextProvider> 
        </Router>
    );
```

};

but this solution is not updating correctly ... how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to access state from context, that component should be consumer to that context. Instead of using that provider in `App`, simply wrap the `App` with that provider

```
export default const App = () => {
   return (
         <AppDataContextProvider> 
              <AppBody />
         </AppDataContextProvider> 
   );
};

const AppBody = () => {
    const {appData, setAppData} = useContext(AppDataContext);     // free to use
    return (
       <Router>
          ... 
        </Router>
    );
};
```